# SSISS no procesa bien los datos de un xml

Tags: sql-server, xml, ssis

Estoy cogiendo varios XML de una carpeta y proceso los datos que me interesa, los meto en distintas tablas de mi BD en SQL Server.
Pues resulta que solo me coge algunos datos de estos XML en unas tablas y en otras me mete los datos de la "plantilla" en vez de los que les toca.
¿Alguien sabe por qué puede ocurrir esto?
Muchas gracias :D

*Edit Explico todo detalladamente*
Uso un bucle ForEach y dentro una Tarea de Flujo
[image: bucle ForEach y Flujo]

Aquí os pongo las variables que utilizo y configuración.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Dentro de la Tarea de Flujo tengo un simple Origen XML que va a Destino BD Oled, da igual que ponga conversión de datos, me duplica los datos igual.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Os pongo como tengo configurada la "plantilla" del XML y su .xsd, los tengo en distintas carpetas, porque me facilita el trabajo así para después, lo he probado en la misma carpeta y me sigue haciendo el duplicado.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Le pongo a la BD la tabla donde quiero que me lo ponga y sus asignaciones
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y aquí tenéis el resultado de los datos duplicados.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hay otros nodos en el mismo XML que no me ocurre esto, por eso no tengo ni idea de porqué me ocurre solo con algunos y con otros no.

Y si, he mirado los valores en los XML que procesa para verificar que no son los mismos valores.

*Edit 2*
He hecho lo que me habéis dicho pero sigue sin funcionar. 
Cambiar en el origen XML el modo acceso a datos y poner la variable del For Each:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Y sigue duplicando datos, después he cambiado el "ValidateExternalMetaData" a False y seguia igual, sin funcionar:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
También he probado a cambiar el "ValidateExternalMetaData" del destino OLE DB y tampoco.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
¿Alguna idea más?

Comment: Sin más detalles, es imposible identificar el problema.

Comment: Te explico mas extenso a ver si me hago entender, 
SSIS necesita una "plantilla" del XML para tratar a todos los XML por igual.
Imagínate que tengo una etiqueta en los XML que se llama <datos1>,  en la plantilla la etiqueta tiene el siguiente valor <datos1>24</datos1>, y en el siguiente XML por ejemplo tiene el valor <datos1>50<datos1>, pues SSIS me lo pasa como 24 en vez de como 50, y así con todos los XML que procesa, que hay 15 XML, en los 15 el valor de <datos1> lo pone como 24, en cambio cojo otros valores (generalmente strings) y esos si los coge bien.

Comment: Su pregunta mejoraría si proporcionara una reproducción mínima del XML de origen y cómo se debe extraer https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Ya he editado y puesto mas completa la pregunta, gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Crea duplicados por cada archivo en el directorio, ya que *está leyendo n veces el archivo C:\XML\0Plantilla.XML*

Revisa que en **Origen XML**, tienes fijo el valor de ubicación XML, deberías estar usando la variable enumerada por el foreach, User::FullFilePath para referirte con cada iteración a un nuevo XML, lo que implica cambiar el **modo de acceso a datos** de este paso del flujo de datos.

Muchas veces este error también se debe a falta de inicialización de la variable enumeradora en tiempo de diseño. **Ponle un valor predeterminado de cadena vacia en tiempo de diseño.**

En el Origen XML, propiedades deja en falso la validación de metadatos externos (ValidateExternalMetadata = false)

Comment: Si cambio el modo de acceso a datos y lo pongo con "Archivo de XML de variable" y le pongo el User::FileFullPath, dejando el .xsd o generando otro, me sigue duplicando los datos. Si lo pongo en "Datos XML de Variable" poniendo de nuevo User::FileFullPath me da un error que dice: Los datos de nivel raíz no son válidos. linea 1, posicion 1.

Comment: El enfoque 1 es correcto, pero falta ver XML y XSD en tu pregunta. La respuesta ha sido ampliada, favor intentar los cambios anexados

Comment: Hola DEVX75, he editado la pregunta, sigo sin poder resolver mi duda. Muchas gracias.